# docker multi-host networking cluster-advertise option

Tags: networking, docker

I was curious about what does

> --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth1:2376"

exactly do? does it send some broadcast messages on eth1 interface? how secure is that?
or does it just advertise it's ip to K/V storage defined via options? (consul, for example)

Comment: https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/17364 and https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17047 are interesting, but don't answer *precisely* your question.